# Причина краша приложений ios

Tags: ios, swift, отладка

собственно вопрос такой: после переезда в другую область, мои приложения которые я разрабатываю и тестирую на своем iPhone 7 plus перестали запускаться, стартует экран LaunchScreen.storyboard, после этого приложения вылетают. В Xcode нет ошибок. Если есть какие то мысли то подскажите направление в каком можно копать. Я новичок в iOS разработке. Буду рад любой помощи!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, причина в бесплатной лицензии разработчика. В этом случае, нужно периодически (примерно через 2-3 дня) переустанавливать/обновлять разработанные приложения на устройстве для тестирования.

Comment: Понятно, благодарю вас